# how to avoid unique columns in group by?

Tags: sql, count, db2, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I am trying execute this query

```
Select ps.id,count(ps.id) as idCount,p.date 
from table1 p
join table2 PS on p.fq = PS.fq 
group by ps.id,p.date
```

And getting a result like this

```
XYZ11   1   2020-10-23 12:26:35
XYZ11   1   2020-11-05 15:55:20
ABC00   1   2020-11-04 17:56:42
ABC00   1   2020-10-23 12:26:35
```

But instead of this i want my results like

```
XYZ11   2 date?
ABC00   2
```

but wanted to include  date as well how do i avoid this in group by because these are unique values.

Comment: There's nothing in your example that shows where the values for "complaint id" would come from!? You have only "site id" and "complaint date".

Comment: sorry i was talking about complaint date

Comment: But which date do you want, as there are multiple choices?

Comment: all of them it will be great if i can see them in different columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show all the dates, you can use the LISTAGG aggregrate function in DB2. This will concatenate the dates together in a single column using the specified separator.

```
SELECT ps.id, COUNT(ps.id) AS idCount, LISTAGG(p.date, ',') AS Dates
FROM table1 p
JOIN table2 ps ON p.fq = ps.fq 
GROUP by ps.id
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to remove the date from the `select` and `group by` clauses:

```
select ps.id, count(*) as idcount
from table1 p
join table2 ps on p.fq = ps.fq
group by ps.id
```

This gives you one row per `id`, along with the count of rows in each group.